# Identifying color sequence in opencv

Tags: opencv, colors, detection

I have set of images with four possible color R, G, B and Y. In front of camera I have sequence of four images with any possible combination of color. For ex. R,R,G,B or R,G,B,Y etc. In order to find the correct sequence which algorithm or approach is best?

I have added an example image.[image]

The code should return correct sequence as RGBG.

Comment: You can convert the image to hsv plane and check color. It would be good if you could add a sample image.

Comment: I have added an image. Please help me out here.

Comment: Is the image size and square size always constant?

Comment: almost constant.There may be difference of 5-10 pixels

Comment: And background is always white? also color of square is always same? or any change in lighting conditions?

Comment: Color of square is always same. But background can vary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23206/discussion-between-abid-rahman-k-and-sum2000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned before, convert the image to HSV plane. HSV plane is more better to choose a specific color. (Code is in Python)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img  = cv2.imread('sofqn.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Then binarize the image. You can use threshold() function. But I don't know how your brightness would be. So I for edge detection with Canny(). And find contours in it.

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Then for each contour (you can consider contour as an object in your image for now), find its area. If it is small, it is noise, avoid it. Else, we find a bounding rectangle for it, which gives us its topleft corners(x,y), width(w),height(h). From that, we find center point of the square. Check its color in HSV image, and check if it is R,G,B,Y. We put them, ie centroids (cx,cy) and color in a list, (or array). Finally we sort them as per x coordinate, so that first row corresponds to first square and so on.

```
res = []
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cx,cy = x+w/2, y+h/2
        color = hsv[cy,cx,0]

        if (color < 10 or color > 170):
            res.append([cx,cy,'R'])
        elif(50 < color < 70):
            res.append([cx,cy,'G'])
        elif(20 < color <40):
            res.append([cx,cy,'Y'])
        elif(110 < color < 130):
            res.append([cx,cy,'B'])

res = sorted(res,key = lambda res : res[0])
colors = [x[2] for x in res]
print colors
```

This gives me the result : `['R', 'G', 'B', 'G']`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying this right now. Awesome explanation

Comment: Can this code be useful for Color Sequence Recognition in application where you must find appropriate color sequence in cable wires?

Example image: https://ibb.co/c40aO5

Here we have to check if wires are in appropriate order, so only the sequence of color : Red, Black, Yellow, Brown, Pink, Yellow, Blue, Green, White, Black, Red is OK, other combinations are NOTOK!

Can anyone have a suggestion how to solve this?